# SQL Time to Text

Tags: sql, sql-server

If the `date = '1900-01-01'` how would I write a `CASE` statement so that the result would return `'Enroute'`?

```
,case 
   when (cast(Arrival_TS as date)) = '1900-01-01' then cast('Enroute' as text) 
   else cast(Arrival_TS as date) 
 end ArrivalDate
```

Error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 11 Operand type clash: text is
> incompatible with date

Comment: Why do you think you need to cast `Arrival_TS` to date? Is that column not already a date (or related) datatype? And NEVER use the text or image datatypes - they have been deprecated for years.

Answer (score 1):

A `case` expression only returns one type.  If you want `'Enroute'` as a value, the type needs to be a string.  So:

```
(case when (cast(Arrival_TS as date)) = '1900-01-01'
      then 'Enroute'
      else convert(varchar(255), Arrival_TS, 23)
 end) as ArrivalDate
```

You can choose the appropriate format for the `convert()`.  This uses my preferred format of YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `SQL_VARIANT` as below:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN(CAST(@Arrival_TS AS DATE)) = '1900-01-01'
           THEN CAST('Enroute' AS SQL_VARIANT)
           ELSE CAST(@Arrival_TS AS DATE)
       END ArrivalDate;
```

Please check the db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=927139b0234b5cd7a17d73b6cf79eab9).